# Check for MediaPlayer Playing? How?

Tags: android, audio

Anyone know how to check to see if MediaPlayer is being played.  In a test, before I added the if statement, the audio played fine, but now I get a force closed. What I want is that when someone clicks another button, the current audio stops and the new audio plays.  I thought that would be easy, but it seems not.  I thought I did the code correctly. Is my code correct?  What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                long id) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.release();

            }

            else {

            if (pos==0) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2200);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==1) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2201);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==2) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2202);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==3) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2203);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==4) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2204);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==5) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2205);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==6) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2206);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==7) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2207);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==8) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2208);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==9) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2209);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==10) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2210);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==11) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2211);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==12) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2212);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==13) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2213);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==14) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2214);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==15) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2215);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==16) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.v_2216);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before calling isPlaying() and set it to null after all release calls, so the release doesn't get called twice.

```
  if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {    
       mp.stop();
       mp.release();
       mp = null;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, this gave me the same error too.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: NullExceptionPointer error, or something of the kind

Comment: Sorry, let me try again...I didn't see that

Comment: I tried this, but the problem now is, that after I tap the audio, it plays only once.  After I tap it again, it force close...hmmm....

Comment: Sorry, my man..No go...How is this done.  I want it to behave like the media player on my phone.  When you click a song, it plays, but if you click another song while it's playing, the song stops and the new song plays...I would think this is a simple common procedure in programming.